# Calculating growth rate with initial value using runif and rnorm

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

I am working with a problem in R that has the demand for a product that is normally distributed with a mean of a and standard deviation b. It is estimated to increase c% each year. The market share for year 1 is anywhere between d% and e% with each number in between equally likely, and is expected to grow at f% each year.

I know I need to use the rnorm function for the demand
`rnorm(1000,a,b)` and runif function for the market share `runif(1000,1.d,1.e)` (adding the 1 in front for easier calculation) year 1 values.

The problem is asking for what the market share and demand will be over 3 years. I know year 1, but I am not sure how I would set the calculation up in R for years 2 and 3 given the growth rates c and f. I currently have something like `MarketSizeGrowth<-cumprod(c(runif(1000,1.d,1.e),rep(1.f,2)` for the market size but this is definitely wrong.

Comment: It is logically impossible to have a market share which is both equally likely in a given interval [a,b] with a!=b and depend on the value of the last year at the same time.

Comment: The market share being equally likely is just so we can use the runif function to find a random variable for the year 1 value. All subsequent years would depend on that first value that was found. (i.e. I run the runif function and get 1. Year 2's share would grow f% from 1, year 3 would be f% more than year 2's share.